# Assigning value with echo command

Tags: shell

Can somebody say what does this statement do . P.s : I am supernew to shell scripting and i am trying to understand the statement. 
statement :

```
y1=`echo $y $l $tol | awk '{print $1 + $2 - $3}'`
```

Comment: It is summing up 3 variables and assigning result to `y1` variable.

Comment: It `echo`es the three values to standard output, has awk read those values from standard input and then perform some simple math on them and print out the result. That value is then stored in the variable `y1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. The first part: `echo $y $l $tol`:**

The 3 shell variables `y` `l` and `tol` are printed via the `echo` command.

**2. The pipe (`|`):**

That means the output of the prevous command is redirected to the input of the following command (the `awk` command). For more information about redirections see [I/O Redirection](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html).

**3. The second part: `awk '{print $1 + $2 - $3}'`:**

`awk` is a utillity for text manipulation. In this case `awk` reads from the input (what the `echo` command prints out) and processes it line by line. What you see in the awk statement is applied for every line that comes from the input. (In this case it's just one line).

`awk` prints the result of `y+l-tol`, that is one digit now (I assume, depending on what `y`, `l` and `tol` are).

**4. The surrounding backquotes (``):**

That's [command substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html). The shell performs the expansion by executing what is inside the backticks and replacing it with the standard output of the command.

**5. The variable `y1=:**

All that above is not printed to the shell, it's assigned as value to the shell variable called `y1`. After that assignment you can print the value with `echo $y1`.